# If $X_1 \perp X_2 \perp \ldots \perp Z$, where $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid, is $\frac{X_1}{Z}, \ldots ,\frac{X_1}{Z}$ are independent of $Z$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid random variables and $Z$ is independent to each of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, is it necessarily true that $\dfrac{X_1}{Z}, \ldots ,\dfrac{X_1}{Z}$ are independent of $Z$? Here $\perp$ means independence thanks!

Comment: Just examine the case $n=1$: why would $X_1/Z$ be independent of $Z$ in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No,** consider for instance the case where $X_1=X_2=\cdots=X_n=1$ a.s.